# JavaScript access iframe cross domain issue

Tags: javascript, dom, cross-domain

I have a snippet on `www.a.com`

```
<iframe src="www.b.com" id="my-iframe">
  #document
    <html>
      <header>
        //some headers go here
      </header>
      <body>
        <div id="my-iframe-div"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
 </iframe>
```

What I want to achieve is to add one class name on the div inside the iframe

so what I did is

```
const element = document.getElementById('my-iframe').contentWindow.document.getElementById('my-iframe-div');
if(element) element.classList.add('my-iframe-class')
```

which would result in cross domain error, because the `src` attribute is `www.b.com`, but the page is on `www.b.com`

How to implement that? thanks

Comment: cross domain iframe access can be achieved through [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) - because using postMessage allows code on both domains to allow and control such access

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)